# Passed props being undefined in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have my App.js(parent) and restaurantArray.js(child) and passed the props in properly but React is returning that restaurants is undefined. I've also tried destructuring but it doesn't seem to work.

Currently the error I'm getting is:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'restaurants' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
If I don't destructure it then:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'restaurants' of undefined

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import RestaurantArray from './components/RestaurantArray.js';

function App() {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <SearchBar />
        <RestaurantArray restaurants = {restaurants}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

RestaurantArray.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Restaurant from './Restaurant.js';

function RestaurantArray ( {restaurants} ) {
    return(
        <div className = "RestaurantArray">
            {
                restaurants.map(restaurant => {
                    return <Restaurant restaurant = {restaurant}
                                       key = {restaurant.id} />;
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
export default RestaurantArray();
```

Comment: remove () on `export default RestaurantArray()`

Comment: I think this worked! I moved the export default in front of the function heading. Thank you!